# RsiOPCAuto.dll... where to find?

Tags: .net, integration, dde

I need to interface with plant machinery, and at each of our plants, we use RSLinx to communicate with that machinery. According to [this blog post](http://industrial-software.blogspot.com/2009/11/rockwell-opc-automation-with-visual.html?showComment=1355333939007#c5033188581763197471) it's relatively easy to read data from RSLinx:

```
    Dim OpcServer As New RsiOPCAuto.OPCServer
    Dim OpcGroup As RsiOPCAuto.OPCGroup
    Dim OpcItem As RsiOPCAuto.OPCItem
    Dim vItem As String = ""

    Try
        OpcServer.Connect("RSLinx Remote OPC Server", "192.168.195.128")

        ' Add this group to the shared topic
        OpcGroup = OpcServer.OPCGroups.Add("INDEC")
        OpcGroup.IsSubscribed = False
        OpcGroup.IsActive = False
        OpcGroup.UpdateRate = 250

        OpcGroup.OPCItems.DefaultAccessPath = "OPC_Test"
        OpcGroup.OPCItems.AddItem("OPC_Bit001", 1)
        OpcItem = OpcGroup.OPCItems.Item(1)

        OpcItem.Read(2, vItem)

        OpcItem = Nothing
        OpcServer.OPCGroups.RemoveAll()
        OpcGroup = Nothing
        OpcServer.Disconnect()
        OpcServer = Nothing

        'Add and Error the list box
    Catch ex As PlatformNotSupportedException
        MsgBox("Error In Get Plc Data: " & ex.Message)
    End Try

    MsgBox(vItem)
```

But... it says that I need to add a reference to RsiOPCAuto.dll, but I don't know:

1. Where to find it
2. What all it can do
3. Anything about licensing it

Specifically, though, I'm curious if anyone knows where I can find that DLL.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this file RsiOpcAuto.dll is located in c/programfiles/commonfiles/Rockwell, as long as you have a licenced rslinx oem or professional (gateway) version 2.54 or under.